# PostgreSQL or MySQL copy paste deploy

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I'm looking for a simple way to deploy and test an application that requires a SQL backend. Is there a SQL engine like MYSQL or PostgreSQL that would allow me to do the following:

1. Zip Database + Binaries into a single file.
2. Copy to target machine
3. Unzip and run MySQL.exe \ Postgress.exe
4. Connect local application

At 1st glace I thought PostgreSQL may allow for this but it already complained that I can't run it as a user with Admin privileges.

I'm trying to keep this very simple and lightweight. I don't need and crazy SQL features.

Comment: Might want to look at sqlite

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken SQLLite does not have a standalone option, it's designed to be embedded into you application.

Comment: But the "embedded" part of SQLite is just using the SQLite driver for whatever language you're using so it isn't any different than using any other database (except that you don't need extra processes for the database server). The data is just a single file and you can muck around with that file using the `sqlite3` CLI tool if you need to do things by hand. The type system is very loose but that shouldn't be a problem for simple things.

Comment: I see - thanks. The application that I'm using needs to be able to something that provides a standard ODBC type connection. Does SQLLite provide something like that?

Comment: maybe you can take a look to Apache Derby: http://db.apache.org/derby/

Comment: Apache Derby seems perfect - thanks Barranka. I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best answers are likely to be firebird as an embedded engine and sqlite.  Use sqlite if your needs are more modest, and firebird if you need greater abilities to scale up.